# Array name underscore meaning

Tags: python, python-3.x, gaussian

I have a question about the sample code below. I am sure that the values being passed to the `gp.predict` line are the values from `X` array. But, why is it used as `X_`? Could somebody explain what `X_` or rather an array `name_` mean in python?

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(4)
X = rng.uniform(0, 5, 10)[:, np.newaxis]
y = np.sin((X[:, 0] - 2.5) ** 2)
gp.fit(X, y)

# Plot posterior
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
X_ = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y_mean, y_std = gp.predict(X_[:, np.newaxis], return_std=True)
plt.plot(X_, y_mean, 'k', lw=3, zorder=9)
plt.fill_between(X_, y_mean - y_std, y_mean + y_std,
                 alpha=0.2, color='k')
```

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It some convention used by the writer of this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a "proper" use of the trailing underscore.  It seems to be just an arbitrary variable here.

[According to the Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles):

> single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.

You'll often see a trailing underscore used to label something `list_`, or `class_`, etc.